# How to override the minimum height in SliverAppBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliverappbar

I am having a problem where I can't decrease the `SliverAppBar` as I need. I found out that it has some kind of minHeight constraint that has to deal with some animation and layout stuff. I have a `TextButton.icon` and some `Text` in it which don't take up much space. I need the behavior of the `SliverAppBar` of `floating`. Is there a way to decrease the height freely without any constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SliverToBoxAdapter` and then use a `Sizedbox` or for more flexibility you can use `SliverPersistentHeader`.

```dart
class MySliverAppBarDelegant extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 40; //use same for fixed height
  @override
  double get minExtent => 30;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) =>
      false;
}
```

And use  like

```dart
SliverPersistentHeader(
  delegate: MySliverAppBarDelegant(),
  pinned: true,
)
```

Comment: yeah, I tried this solution but found a more simpler way for me. I adjusted the toolbarHeight property and worked fine for me but also until a certain height. THX anyway <3

Answer (score 0):

You can set set custom SliverAppBar height and expanded app bar height by using this approach simply and can use your expanded area .
Here is sample code

```
SliverAppBar(
              // this is where I would like to set some minimum constraint
              expandedHeight: 300,
              floating: false,
              pinned: true,
              bottom: PreferredSize(                       // Add this code
                preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(60.0),      // Add this code
                child: Text(''),                           // Add this code
              ),                                           // Add this code
              flexibleSpace: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                height: 340,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 60,
                    ),
                    Expanded(child: Container()),
                    Text('TEST'),
                  ],
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/400/400'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover)),
              ),
            )
```